# Finding the Exact Value

Tags: trigonometry

How would one go about finding the exact value of $\theta$ in the following:$\sqrt{3}\tan \theta -1 =0$? I am unsure of how to begin this question. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: are you familiar with $\arctan$ function?

Comment: I am not familiar with that function

Comment: @Tim I meant the first, sorry for the confusion. It isn't cubed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\sqrt{3}\tan \theta -1 =0\implies \sqrt{3}\tan \theta =1\implies \tan \theta=1/\sqrt{3}$

Recall from SOH CAH TOA, that $\tan \theta=\text{opposite}/\text{adjacent}$, so in this case $1$ is the opposite side and $\sqrt{3}$ is the adjacent side.

[image]

The above is a special triangle. Since you know that $\tan \theta=1/\sqrt{3}$, it follows that the angle $\theta=\pi/6$. However since $\tan \theta$ is a trigonometric periodic function, that value will come up again, and again. (Just like  $\sin0=\sin2\pi).$

$\tan \theta$ has a period of $\pi.$

So to be fully accurate, $\theta=\pi/6 +n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Thank you! So theta= pi/4(+-)pi(n), 5pi/4(+-) is not a solution?

Comment: theta= pi/4(+-)pi(n), 5pi/4(+-) is not a solution.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Would you mind me asking what I could do to get through finding the exact value of 2cos^(2)(θ)+cos(θ)-1=0?

Comment: $2\cos^{2} \theta+\cos \theta-1=0 \implies 2\cos^{2}+\cos \theta =1 \implies \cos \theta (2\cos \theta+1)=1\implies \cos \theta =1 \implies \theta =2n\pi, n\in \mathbb{Z}$ However, $\cos \theta(2\cos \theta +1)=1$ also implies that $2\cos \theta+1=1 \implies 2\cos \theta =0 \implies \cos \theta =0 \implies \theta = (2n-1)/\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Wow!! Thank you so much :)!

Answer (score 2):

If $\sqrt{3}\tan \theta - 1= 0$ then $\sqrt{3}\tan\theta = 1$ and $\tan\theta = 1/\sqrt{3}$. Hence $\theta =\arctan(1/\sqrt{3}) = \frac{\pi}{6}$.

Notice that the graph $y = \tan\theta$ repeats every $\pi$-radians. Hence, all solutions are given by

$$\theta = \frac{\pi}{6} + \pi n$$

where $n$ is any whole number.